# Why use a hash bucket to handle Out-of-vocabulary tokens in embedding layers?

Tags: tensorflow, word-embeddings

For example, in the nnlm-en-dim128 model in thug (https://tfhub.dev/google/nnlm-en-dim128/1). It says

> Small fraction of the least frequent tokens and embeddings (~2.5%) are replaced by hash buckets. Each hash bucket is initialized using the remaining embedding vectors that hash to the same bucket.

My questions is why does it work? What is the benefit of this approach? What is the intuition behind it?

Comment: Why does it work, compared to what? What's the approach you have in mind instead? It'll be easier to explain in that context.